# Codeigniter mysql DESCRIBE

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, bind, quotes, describe

I'm a bit new to codeigniter and I'm trying to run this simple query:

```
DESCRIBE `table_name`;
```

I tried this:

```
$sql = 'DESCRIBE ?';
$desc = $this->db->query($sql, $table)->result();
```

Which creates this query:

```
DESCRIBE 'table_name';
```

As you can see, the wrong quotes are being outputted when I bind the $table variable; they are value quotes ('), not table quotes (`). Am I doing this wrong?

thank you!

Comment: Related, if it's of interest, I wrote a *Describe All Tables* in [this Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38679580).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CodeIgniter's query bindings will escape things for you.  It assumes that the data is a value, not a table name.

You're gunna have to escape the value yourself.

```
$table = $this->db->escape_str($table);
$sql = "DESCRIBE `$table`";
$desc = $this->db->query($sql)->result();
```